# How to configure OAuth2 connection in Android?

Tags: android, rest, post, oauth-2.0, okhttp

I need to connect my app to a secure back-end via **OAuth2** server. The main problem is that I can't get a token. I have the necessary parameters like clientID, secret and go on. But I need to make a **POST** request. I decided to use **OkHttp OAuth2 client** ([library' GitHub](https://github.com/corcoran/okhttp-oauth2-client)). It doesn't work and I'm not sure it makes a POST. So I wrote simple a OkHttp request and put all stuff to post method. But I still get `token=null`.
It looks like this:

```
OkHttpClient client1 = new OkHttpClient();
      RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
          .add("client_id", clientID)
          .add("client_secret", clientSecret)
          .add("grant_type", "password")
          .build();

      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(site)
          .post(formBody)
          .build();
```

And then I expect to see the token as a part of response. Other version is like at a guide at library' github. Maybe someone worked with this or can tell a better solution?

Comment: Use Retrofit library. You can take some article guide [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to integrate OAuth 2.0 in a project a while ago to use Google contacts. I used this lib: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android

You can also see some important documentation in here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

And an example:

**Fragment.java:**

```
AuthorizationServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = 
    new AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
            Uri.parse(GoogleConstants.OAUTH_URL) /* auth endpoint */,
            Uri.parse(GoogleConstants.TOKEN_URL) /* token endpoint */,
            null
    );

AuthorizationRequest.Builder authRequestBuilder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
            serviceConfiguration,
            getString(GoogleConstants.CLIENT_ID),
            ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
            Uri.parse(GoogleConstants.REDIRECT_URI))
            .setScope(GoogleConstants.OAUTH_SCOPE);

AuthorizationRequest request = authRequestBuilder.build();

AuthorizationService authorizationService = new AuthorizationService(getActivity());

String action = GoogleConstants.APP_ACTION;
Intent postAuthorizationIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleActivity.class);

postAuthorizationIntent.setAction(action);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
      PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, postAuthorizationIntent, 
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

authorizationService.performAuthorizationRequest(request, pendingIntent);
```

**Activity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    checkIntentAction(intent);
}

...

private void checkIntentAction(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            switch (action) {
                case GoogleConstants.APP_ACTION:
                    if (!intent.hasExtra(USED_INTENT)) {
                        handleAuthorizationResponse(intent);
                        intent.putExtra(USED_INTENT, true);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}

...

private void handleAuthorizationResponse(final @NonNull Intent intent) {
    final AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(intent);

    if (response != null) {
        final AuthorizationService service = new AuthorizationService(this);
        service.performTokenRequest(response.createTokenExchangeRequest(), 
            new AuthorizationService.TokenResponseCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onTokenRequestCompleted(@Nullable TokenResponse tokenResponse, 
                         @Nullable AuthorizationException exception) {
               ...
              }
            });
    }
}
```